# What is the difference between contraction and elision?

Tags: terminology, contractions, elision

So, what is the difference between the terms? Is it right to say that elision is a specific case of contraction? Another version I've I ran onto was that these were slightly different terms as contraction always refers to the case when there's more than one word.

Comment: My understanding is that contraction is usually a specific case of elision. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)): *English has a number of contractions, mostly involving the elision of a vowel*

Comment: No, they're referring to different things. _Elision_ refers to **sounds** -- phonemes, consonants and vowels, not alphabet letters -- and their absence when they would be expected. _Contraction_, on the other hand, refers to **words** that fuse together and are treated as a single word. Naturally, contraction almost always involves elision of some sounds, but it also involves more elaborate phonology, like _will not_ ==> _won't_, or _should not have_ ==> _shouldna_.

Comment: see 1.3 at the [definition for contraction](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/contraction)

Comment: @Araucaria: You're right. I shouldn't comment before I've had coffee in the morning. (You know, it was one of those *e* words!) -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An elision refers specifically to the [removal of sounds from speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision), while a contraction refers to a shortened version of writing words, that can represent that spoken elision in English.  [A contraction though is not always a written representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)) of that elision because a contraction can represent other things as well.

Additionally, [an elision is **NOT** always turned into a contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision) in writing, though.

Comment: Contractions exist in spoken language. More importantly, they may exist in languages which have no formal writing system. People who can't read or write still nonetheless use contractions in English.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for your response.  I don't believe my answer precludes the option of contractions existing in spoken language.

Comment: To me, the answer seems to contrast the spoken nature of elision with what is portrayed as the written nature of contraction.

Comment: @Araucaria Admittedly, the answer does not emphasize the oral use of contractions, but I think it serves the purpose the question.  I don't think adding anything to the answer would help the user understand better.  It may make it more confusing.